# How can I prevent ap elements with drag function from overlapping?

Tags: javascript, slider, puzzle

I'm creating a slider puzzle, I've got each section of the image in it's own ap div, each with the same z-index. I've restricted the drag movement to within the confines of the puzzle, but the ap divs are overlapping when I drag them. I was hoping the same z-index would prevent them from overlapping, but when I drag, they overlap. How can I prevent them from overlapping? I'm using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. Any thoughts?

Comment: What is an "ap element" or "ap div?"

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to prevent them from overlapping using the standard drag-and-drop facilities found in popular libraries like Dojo or jQuery.  They're supposed to overlap; it's supposed to allow you to drop.  At best, these libraries support borders you cannot cross, a bounding box for the drag operation.  For your code, which sounds more complex, you will need to examine the bounding box code, write your own collision detection code for all the objects in your game's region, and incorporate that into the drag operation.

Setting the z-index has no effect on this.  Browsers automagically adjust the z-index (often fractionally) to allow overlapping when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Heather body..

Please look at these websites,

```
<http://www.webreference.com/authoring/style/sheets/page_structuring2/>
<http://www.cs.txstate.edu/~rs01/1308/lectures/week5/5-1.htm>
```

Comment: Prathap: She's using a library that enables drag.  Dragging is usually done with absolute positioning with respect to a parent object.  This isn't about the browser's layout engine, or about using CSS to arrange document flow correctly.  How do the articles to which you've linked help Ms. Boddy?